# Picture manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I would like to create a module that allow user to edit picture taken from camera with some filter (color operation like saturation, intensity, ...) and some items like hats, mustache, and much more.

I will create items (png with transparent background) but I would like to find a library that can help me to add item on existing picture and maybe change color if the library allow that.

Could you tell me if there is an existing library that can help me to do that?

EDIT: I would like to save the final image in a file, not only displayed

Comment: try google or a different search engine, that helps

Comment: I did it but the reason i post it here is to know if there is an great lib that most developers use. I don't know canvas in HTML and what is the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/), provides what you need.
EDIT:
Use this to save an image from the canvas:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = "img.png";
link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
link.click();
```

Comment: it seems to be very good but just one question, is it possible to save the final image in a file after editing?

Comment: I have an angular application and I don't find the right way to use it correctly, I will post here my result when I solve the problem.
There is a module called 'angular-fabric' created by Michael J. Calkins but there isn't any doc, so I think I will use the fabric.js as it is. Thank you for informations

Answer (score -1):

try here
[CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/)

i think it is what you are looking for